# String not correct date time format

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I want to convert a string to DateTime, but I get the following error.

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

```
int firstDayOfMonth = 1;
int lastDayOfMonth = 31;
int month = 3;
int year = 2006;

string sStartDate = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", firstDayOfMonth, month, year);
string eEndDate = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", lastDayOfMonth, month, year);

//This one works 
    DateTime sDate = Convert.ToDateTime(startDate, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat);
//This one doesnt work
    DateTime eDate = Convert.ToDateTime(eEndDate, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat);
```

Then I tried this

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(year, month, lastDayOfYear);
```

But then it gives me `3/1/2006` but I need it in `dd/MM/yyyy`

What can I do to convert the string to `dd/MMyyyy`?

Comment: It looks like your current culture is set to `en-US` but you are expecting it to be `en-GB`. Check your control panel settings.

Comment: What is your `CurrentCulture`?

Answer (score 8):

Why don't you use the `DateTime` constructor instead of `DateTime.Parse`?

```
DateTime sDate = new DateTime(year, month, firstDayOfMonth);
```

> What can i do to convert the string to dd/MM/yyyy

You can conveerrt the `DateTime` to `string` using the proper format string and `InvariantCulture` to [prevent that `/` gets replaced by the actual date separator of your culture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#dateSeparator).

```
string sStartDate = sDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Because then the order of month and day are swapped around. It gives MM/dd/yyyy and I want dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: @MikeBarnes: you are confusing a `DateTime`-value  and how it is represented in the debugger (or wherever). A `DateTime` has just a value and no format. Note that i've edited  my answer to show how to convert the DateTime to the desired string.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to convert string to date with specific format you can use `DateTime.ParseExact` such as the following example

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("9/1/2009", "M/d/yyyy", 
                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Convert.ToDateTime` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.convert.todatetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) uses your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) settings *by default*.

Your `sStartDate` is `1/3/2006` but your `eEndDate` is `31/3/2006`.

If this `1/3/2006` can be parsed successfully, that means your current culture has `d/M/yyyy` or `M/d/yyyy` (with your current culture [date separator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator.aspx) of course) as a [standard date and time format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but doesn't have `dd/M/yyyy` format.

You can find all standard date and time format of your `CurrentCulture` like;

```
foreach (var format in CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.
                       DateTimeFormat.
                       GetAllDateTimePatterns())
{
     Console.WriteLine(format);
}
```

Other than that, I agree with all what [Tim Schmelter says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28165907/447156).